# "Laravel API Login Endpoint - Getting 419 Error (Proxy Reauthentication Required)"

Tags: laravel

I have login API in Laravel , but it giving me 419 error. I have provided my code below:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
      try{
        $rules = [
            'phone' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
          return response()->json(['status' => false, 'data' => [], 'error' => $validator->errors()]);
        }

        $credentials = request(['phone', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
          return response()->json(['status' => false, 'data' => [], 'error' => ["message" => "Email /                          password didn't match."]]);
        }

        if(auth()->user()->email_verified == 'No')
        {
          auth()->logout();
          return response()->json(['status' => false, 'data' => [], 'error' => ["message" => 'Your Email is not Verified!']]);
        }

        if(auth()->user()->ban == 1)
        {
          auth()->logout();
          return response()->json(['status' => false, 'data' => [], 'error' => ["message" => 'Your Account Has Been Banned.']]);
        }

        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'data' => ['token' => $token, 'user' => new UserResource(auth()->user())], 'error' => []]);
      }
      catch(\Exception $e){
        return response()->json(['status' => true, 'data' => [], 'error' => ['message' => $e->getMessage()]]);
      }
    }
```

Here is my form where I provide **csrf** token.

```html
<form class="mloginform" action="{{ route('user.login.submit') }}" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-input">
```

and here is my Route

```
Route::post('login', 'Api\Auth\AuthController@login');
```

**Now what I can do to fix this?**

Comment: What file is your route in? For API routes you don't need csrf tokens.

Comment: Problem solved. There was problem into my URL that I am giving into postman.  Now my problem is solved. Thanks for your response.